# Autohotkey save excel file without seeing overwrite prompt

Tags: excel, automation, autohotkey

I have a autohotkey script that saves the file to a backup location in sharepoint. I can save the file there fine but it keeps asking for a okay to overwrite prompt and I am wondering if it is at all possible to get rid of that.

Code is listed below.

```
ExcelRefresh(File) { ; Function

sharepointPath := "\\sharepoint\Location\SharepointCompleted.xlsx"
oExcel := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible := false
oWorkbook := oExcel.Workbooks.Open(File) 
oWorkbook.RefreshAll
oWorkbook.Save()
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(sharepointPath)
oWorkbook.Close(false)
oExcel.Quit()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was just a simple check if file exists and from there if it does exist I delete the file before I save it to the backup location in SharePoint. Not the cleaning way but it works.

```
IfExist , \\sharepoint\sites\SharepointCompleted.xlsx
;MsgBox, it esxists
FileDelete, \\sharepoint\sites\SharepointCompleted.xlsx

Sleep 15000
```

I added this before I run the function. And so far it has passed my tests.